# Meaning of a result of Gauss on "Mensura" of cyclotomic numbers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ho.history-overview, cyclotomic-fields

(This question [was asked before on mathstackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4826973/meaning-of-some-results-of-gauss-on-cyclotomic-numbers). I received a few useful comments there, which helped me answer it for a special case, but I did not succeed in proving the general case.)

In an unpublished fragment of Gauss entitled ["on the theory of complex numbers"](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN23599524X?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B391%5D%2C%22pan%22%3A%7B%22x%22%3A0.366%2C%22y%22%3A0.766%7D%2C%22view%22%3A%22toc%22%2C%22zoom%22%3A0.481%7D), written by him around 1810,  Gauss made early inroads into the theory of cyclotomic numbers, which are numbers that can be written as $f(\epsilon) = a_0+a_1\epsilon+a_2\epsilon^2+\dots+a_{n-1}\epsilon^{n-1}$ when $n$ is a prime number and $\epsilon^n = 1$ ($\epsilon$ is a non-trivial root of unity). Just to illustrate its importance, in chapter [I] he proves Fermat's last theorem for $n=3,5$, and in chapter [V] he states the following theorem on "cyclotomic units" later established by Ernst Kummer:

> every unit of the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}[\epsilon]$ is a product of numbers of the  form $$\frac{\epsilon^{\alpha}-\epsilon^{\beta}}{\epsilon^{\gamma}-\epsilon^{\delta}}$$

According to Paul Bachmann, another theorem later established by Kummer (in 1847), which states that a cyclotomic integer $f(\rho)$ whose analytical modulus (analytical norm) is equal to 1 must be $\pm\rho^n$, also occurs here for the first time.

My question is concerned with a result Gauss gives in chapter [III], which posits a certain upper bound for a quantity Gauss calls "mensura" in the case $n=5$, in terms of a quantity he calls determinant $D$. The quantity he calls determinant is defined to be:

$D=f(\epsilon)f(\epsilon^2)\cdots f(\epsilon^{n-1})$

so it is almost the algebraic norm of the cyclotomic number. However, the deeper meaning of the notion of "mensura", which literally means "scale" , is not very clear to me. It is defined to be the sum of analytic norms of $f(\epsilon)$ and all of its complex conjugates except $f(\epsilon^0)$:

$$Mensura = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(\epsilon^k)f(\epsilon^{-k})$$

Gauss states the following inequallity:

> Highest mensura = $2(\frac{sin(2\pi/5)}{sin(\pi/5)}+\frac{sin(\pi/5)}{sin(2\pi/5)})\sqrt{D}\approx 4.472\sqrt{D}$

In the comments to this question in mathstackexchange, I proved it for cyclotomic numbers with only 2 terms, $f(\epsilon)=a+b\epsilon$. However, the expression of the determinant $D$ for general cyclotomic numbers is very long and complicated, and I did not recognize the general pattern in this inequality. Even for the simplest case of only 2 terms, my proof was very "ad-hoc" and unilluminating, while Gauss states it as a one-line result (without much calculation).

Therefore it will be great and much appreciated by me if someone will explain it in an elegant manner. By the way, in the remarks to this fragment, Paul Bachmann comments that Gauss's considerations in chapter [III] are related to the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[\epsilon]$ is a unique factorization domain (for $\epsilon^5=1$).

So my question is how to prove this inequlity? and what is the meaning of the notion of "mensura"?

Comment: You can bound the norm using the "measure" via the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means; this can be used for showing that the ring of integers in the fifth roots of unity are norm-Euclidean. Lenstra did this in one of his papers.

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer - I think the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means helps give a lower bound for the "Mensura", since the determinant $D$ is related to the geometric mean and the mensura is related to the arithmetic mean. However, Gauss's inequality gives an upper bound for the mensura, so the inequality of means does not help here.

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer - thank you for commenting that there is a paper by Lenstra on exactly this topic. I think I found it - is it the article "EUCLID'S ALGORITHM IN CYCLOTOMIC FIELDS "?  because in the first page of it, under the subtitle "The general measure and Euclid's algorithm", Lenstra writes: "Following Gauss, we define the general measure µ...", and his definition of "general measure" corresponds exactly to Gauss's notion of "Mensura".